# How to avoid bad bounce rate and boost good bounce rate?

Tags: website-design, ux-field

I'm working on a comparing website. We got lots of traffic from the blog article, yet the bounce rate is so high. We perform well on acquisition but bad on keeping the user in the site then generate good bounce rate. (checked on Similar web most user bounce to non-reveune generated website) Do u got any suggestion/ sample to enhance the situation with good bounce rate?

Comment: Tell us why the users would stay. What things does the site do to keep these users?

Comment: This makes no sense without further context of the business, the site, and the audience. Could you provide thoose?

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a very vast topic and a better insight into the KPIs and Analytics can help to refine the solution.

However, the key points for your situation to avoid a bad bounce rate and boost a good bounce rate are:

- Put readable and legible contents.
- Please don't put large chunks
- Dontdisrupt the UX by putting irrelevant popups
- Do your A/B tests and put a compelling CTA
- Try to Achieve great brand Storytelling
- Measure the freshness of your blog before deploying
- Start targeting the High-Value keywords
- Create multiple landing pages for High-Value keywords

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like people are coming to your site, reading the article and then leaving. Even though acquisition is high (excellent news!) it sounds like you want them to keep engaging with the rest of your site. Here are some things to try:

- Add links to related articles at the bottom of each article page (or in a sidebar). You can design this to be visually compelling with photos and teasers to entice the reader to learn more.
- Similarly, add a "Read next" link with some information on it at the bottom.
- Ask the user to sign up for your newsletter and send them future articles. This will count as a microconversion and not a bounce.
- Install a tool like Hotjar to see how far users are getting down each article page (using the scroll map function). Use that to optimize the length of your articles.